IK problem with a rig made from scratch
I made this rig following a Blender rigging course. It has IK leg bones with poles parented to a foot roll bone setup. The problem is, when I spin the root bone, The IK gets messed up after the character rotates 90 degrees.
How can I fix this?



hello could you please share your armature only?

The odds are good that you are copying single-axis (or reduced influence) world space rotation from something.  That will lead to discontinuities like you're seeing.  If you need to copy that kind of rotation, use an extra bone to locked track-- to limit it to a particular axis-- and then copy the full rotation of that bone.

@moonboots file was uploaded.

@Nathan I have no idea what you mentioned. I will look into this

Looked at the file.  The raw reason is you're limiting world-space x-rot of r/l FootRoll.IK.  When you rotate root, you are changing the world-space rotation of that bone such that it now has rotation in world X, outside your limits.  You can remove that constraint, or make it local space, and rotation of root works fine.  However, I don't know that the rest of what you intend will work without that-- it's not necessarily easy to understand what a broken rig is supposed to do.

@Nathan this is correct! Would you post this as the answer?
